# Woocommerce products search with custom fields

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, pre-get-posts

i have a woocommerce e-shop website. My search is searching only in product title, short description and SKU fields. I want to search also in some custom fields (like "_barcode" and "_mpn"). I want to search on products pages, not in admin panel.

I have this script but when i use it in fuctions.php i can't search by product title or short description.

```
function search_filter( $query ) {

    $key_fields = array ( '_barcode', '_mpn', '_sku' );
    $value_field = $query->query_vars['s'];
    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';

    if ( !is_admin() && $value_field != '' ) {

        $filter_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

        foreach ( $key_fields as $one_field ) {
            array_push ( $filter_query , array (
                'key' => $one_field,
                'value' => $value_field,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ) );
        }
        $query->set( 'meta_query' , $filter_query );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'search_filter');
```

Why i can't search by product title or short description when i use this script? Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309800/add-custom-field-value-to-search-result-without-plugin/309900#309900

Comment: i tried and it's working but it's very slow. it's taking about 40 seconds to display the results.

Comment: How many results are you fetching? 40 seconds too long a time for a very crappy server too.

Comment: usually i'm typing a barcode or an sku number. so i'm fetching 1 result. when i'm not using this script the search results are taking about 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

usually i'm typing a barcode or an sku number. so i'm fetching 1 result. when i'm not using this script the search results are taking about 2-3 seconds.
this is my script:

```
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {    
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }
    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join');

function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
          "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
          "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1 OR ".$wpdb->posts.".post_excerpt LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta. ".meta_value LIKE $1 AND ".$wpdb->postmeta. ".meta_key IN ('_barcode','_sku') )", $where );
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'cf_search_where');

function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```